# Cython convert string to unicode

Tags: python, string, unicode, byte, cython

I am trying to use this lib https://github.com/pytries/datrie to manipulate Chinese text .

But I encounter a problem - it has problem to encode decode Chinese unicode:

```
import datrie
text = htmls_2_text(input_dir)
trie = datrie.Trie(''.join(set(text))) # about 2221 unique chars
trie['今天天气真好'] = 111
trie['今天好'] = 222
trie['今天'] = 444

print(trie.items())

[('今义', 444), ('今义义傲兢于', 111), ('今义于', 222)]
```

unique chars: https://pastebin.com/n2i280i8

The result is wrong, obviously there is a decoding/encoding error.

---

Then I look into source code https://github.com/pytries/datrie/blob/master/src/datrie.pyx

```
cdef cdatrie.AlphaChar* new_alpha_char_from_unicode(unicode txt):
    """
    Converts Python unicode string to libdatrie's AlphaChar* format.
    libdatrie wants null-terminated array of 4-byte LE symbols.
    The caller should free the result of this function.
    """
    cdef int txt_len = len(txt)
    cdef int size = (txt_len + 1) * sizeof(cdatrie.AlphaChar)

    # allocate buffer
    cdef cdatrie.AlphaChar* data = <cdatrie.AlphaChar*> malloc(size)
    if data is NULL:
        raise MemoryError()

    # Copy text contents to buffer.
    # XXX: is it safe? The safe alternative is to decode txt
    # to utf32_le and then use memcpy to copy the content:
    #
    #    py_str = txt.encode('utf_32_le')
    #    cdef char* c_str = py_str
    #    string.memcpy(data, c_str, size-1)
    #
    # but the following is much (say 10x) faster and this
    # function is really in a hot spot.
    cdef int i = 0
    for char in txt:
        data[i] = <cdatrie.AlphaChar> char
        i+=1

    # Buffer must be null-terminated (last 4 bytes must be zero).
    data[txt_len] = 0
    return data


cdef unicode unicode_from_alpha_char(cdatrie.AlphaChar* key, int len=0):
    """
    Converts libdatrie's AlphaChar* to Python unicode.
    """
    cdef int length = len
    if length == 0:
        length = cdatrie.alpha_char_strlen(key)*sizeof(cdatrie.AlphaChar)
    cdef char* c_str = <char*> key
    return c_str[:length].decode('utf_32_le')
```

I have tried use the commented block `txt.encode('utf_32_le')` to replace current faster trick, nether work.

I don't see there is any wrong in this code , what is the problem ?

Comment: You do not show how you create `trie`. That is important as you have to pass the constructor the unicode range of the keys it will be able to handle.

Comment: @schwobaseggl  Thank you for the tip, I found `萨` is not in the unique word input, that's why only have 3 items.  Update the quesion.

Comment: Interesting observation: if you initialize it with `trie = datrie.Trie(''.join(set(u'今天天气真好今天好今天')))`, the issue goes away. You could try to find a minimum set of hanzi in `text` which, if removed, fix the issue.

Comment: @gmoss  Few words fix the issue??  nonono, you can't call that fix. You don't understand why I need trie here,  I know it works when there are very few words in Trie . You need try the data I provide https://pastebin.com/n2i280i8 (over 2000 unique char from 100000senctences) to test !

Comment: @Mithril I was just suggesting removing characters for debugging purposes. That would be a possible first step in finding the encoding issue. I am not suggesting you modify your data needs.

Comment: By the way, if you set `bad_chars = ' 伊亏外会两售嘴吸傻勇呈凑嚏坚凡周切》五嘟厢假嘿参准哈K俊何[也呣令剧k共味凶基喃嚅井军吞…伴为便临壁仅V促以噪俯兰号偶击、吉厌土冠吩劲伟人A净升双哎坟a几卧嗨仪壶固刀匆丈再伎堂化嘘“伞到值圾啊L发停啪l七历喊复冒加别催十G免城卑取付卡佩呯修危乳偷侃。分争圈吊唔优务匠侣"在励冷伸去埃BR剖仙叛占公印兼备嘉册于刑喔咚”圣大-冬亮傲吵丹M呕叠佣哪m台呵具境厅唆吐依东功产咻区势呀H半噌博保噜h壳价垂包垒君丧含京吻伽嚼C光及位S啡c们呻刚丢.唰决嘲品呆先仍塞全剪却典份~厄冈不向互众咖咦努中吱匿协叔块Y团古壮关凸T内圆厉—刘多劣享听丰劳吼D哇但叉像华乐塔叙四信习哧坦任呼喂劈下和夕吗吧侦动/嘻?充塍之O因入o仰噻哼处例世佛亡助垫*地嘶咽仁兄响坐兔乖做啜坠呢书j哭右僵哽丑咒则够厨咲唷刹E凄又变坛乡e叨乱u命勾'`, and use `''.join(set(text)-set(bad_chars))`, it will work. Again, I am not suggesting you remove these words, but it's an interesting data point to help you start investigating the bug.

Comment: @gmoss  I have splited the unique words in several groups to do test .For example,       1. `unique_string[:478]` no error      2. `unique_string[:480]` got errors       3. `unique_string[478:480]` no error       4. `unique_string[460:500]` no erros.  This is very confusing.  PS: I have already switched to another lib, but there must be some error in the c code . I just want to figure out what cause this problem.

Comment: Additional, each `unique_string` group had added the test_strings before testing.

Comment: I think this is the problem: https://github.com/pytries/datrie/blob/master/libdatrie/datrie/alpha-map.h#L59

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that this datrie package supports at most 255 values for characters in the keyset: https://github.com/pytries/datrie/blob/master/libdatrie/datrie/alpha-map.h#L59

I recommend using `marisa_trie::RecordTrie` from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/marisa-trie

Unfortunately it's a static data structure, so you cannot modify it after building, but it fully support unicode, serialization to disk, and all sorts of value types.

```
>>> from marisa_trie import RecordTrie
>>> rt = RecordTrie(">I", [(u'今天天气真好', (111,)), (u'今天好', (222,)), (u'今天', (444,))])
>>> for x in rt.items():
...     print x[0], x[1]
...
今天天气真好 (111,)
今天好 (222,)
今天 (444,)
```

(Note that I am using Python 2.7 in this example, hence the `u''` and printing in a loop.)

EDIT

If you absolutely *must* use datrie.Trie, you can exploit this in a rather dumb way:

```
def encode(s):
    return ''.join('%08x' % ord(x) for x in s)

def decode(s):
    return ''.join(chr(int(s[n:n+8], 16)) for n in range(0, len(s), 8))

>>> trie = datrie.Trie('0123456789abcdef')
>>> trie[encode('今天天气真好')] = 111
>>> trie[encode('今天好')] = 222
>>> trie[encode('今天')] = 444
>>> [decode(x) for x in trie.keys()]
['今天', '今天天气真好', '今天好']
```

I used 8 because 32 is the maximum bit-width of any utf8-encoded character. You could save space by computing `max(ord(x) for x in text)` and using that as the padding. Or you could come up with your own encoding scheme that uses at most 255 char values. This was just a very fast and inefficient solution.

Of course, this sort of defeats the purpose of using a trie...

Comment: I think you are right, thanks . More precise, by this line https://github.com/pytries/datrie/blob/master/libdatrie/datrie/triedefs.h#L56  from the dependency `libdatrie` . So the cython code is not wrong, error comes from c code.

Comment: @Mithril just letting you know I edited the answer a bit with a sample solution that uses `datrie.Trie` as well.